# How does one export/import registered servers with passwords?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssms

I have a pretty extensive collection of registered servers on SQL Server Management Studio 2016 on my box.  However, I got a new box and want to move the entire collection there.  So I right-clicked on Local Server Groups, and exported the entire set with user names and passwords.

When I try to import the set onto a new box, I get this error for every server:

[image]

If I try to export/import without user names and password, it all works fine.  But I do need user names and passwords.

What am I missing?

I am using the same windows login (my domain login) and exactly the same version of SSMS (13.0.15900.1).

Answer (score 0):

It will only work on the same machine, not a different one.